# Empty email custom module Magento 2 transportBuilder

Tags: magento2

I have set up an controller to send email:

```
<?php namespace Qxs\Verkoopje\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    private $transportBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($post);

        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
          ->setTemplateIdentifier('qxs_verkoopje_template')
          ->setTemplateOptions([
            'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
          ])
          ->setFrom([
            'name' => 'xx xxxxx',
            'email' => 'info@xxx.net',
          ])
          ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
          ->addTo('xxx@gmail.com')
          ->setReplyTo('info@xxx.net')
          ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();
    }
}
```

email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="qxs_verkoopje_template"
              label="Verkoop je"
              file="verkoopje_mail.html" type="html"
              module="Qxs_Verkoopje" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

verkoopje_mail.html

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Verkoop je"}}  @-->
Test
Test1
Test2
```

The email is sent but the email content / subject are empty. Anybody any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Update ur email template with below code 
verkoopje_mail.html

```
<!--@subject Verkoop je@-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test1</p>
<p>Test2</p>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

After update this upgrade and deploy

Comment: Did not work...

Answer (score 0):

***First, your verkoopje_mail.html is not loaded that why content is blank***]

EnSure that

- **verkoopje_mail.html** should be located at  `app/code/Qxs/Verkoopje/view/frontend/email`.
- Changes the code:

  `'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID`

  **to**

  `'store' =>$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()`
  add inject  `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` for getting  storeManager
- last do the Static content deploy properly

Comment: Nope still no content in the mail